# Get checksums of all packages on a yum repo server

Tags: yum, repository, checksum

I have a server I'm using as a yum reposerver. I've mirrored all the packages I want, and added additional packages in different folders. I've created multiple repos with the createrepo command. There are now multiple levels of folders with a repodata/ folder.

My question is: is there a way to recurse down through each folder and get all the checksum data for every package in every repo?

Comment: Sure - what have you tried?

Comment: @EEAA I considered writing a script that would grab every primary.xml.gz file under a specific directory, open it up, load up the xml file, and parse out the checksums. It seems doable, but pretty ugly. I figured I'd ask if there was a simple way to do it that I was missing before I dived into a messy python script.